# Какие отношения между частями предложения?

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, синтаксический-разбор

Какие отношения между частями (предикативными единицами) этого сложносочиненного, многочленного(как я полагаю) предложения. Части пронумеровала так:

> 1) Впереди рва, пока хватало глаза, пустынно сиял снег, 2) и на нем
>   нарисовано голубел лес, 3) а ближе и левее чуть виднелось какое-то
>   селение.

Наверное между 1 и 2 отношения одновременности, а между 2 и 3 может быть сопоставительные отношения? Или же все три предложения выражают отношения одновременности?

И еще…будет ли фразеологическое выражение **"пока хватало глаза"** образовывать **отдельную предикативную единицу** или все-таки оно входит в состав предикативной единицы №1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Впереди рва, (2)пока хватало глаза, пустынно сиял снег, (3) и на нем **нарисованно** голубел лес, (4) а ближе и левее чуть виднелось какое-то селение.

Предложения (1) и (2) **составляют  СПП**. Придаточное предложение безличное. Союз ПОКА обычно выражает значение времени, но здесь это скорее придаточное степени (снег сиял настолько, насколько хватало глаз)

Союз И связывает СПП и предложение(3), причем (3) **распространяет** СПП, об этом говорит местоимение "на нём".

Группа предложений  СПП и  (3) **сопоставляется** с предложением (4), о чем свидетельствует союз А, а также обстоятельства места "впереди" и "ближе и левее".

Кроме того, между СПП, (3) и (4) существуют отношения **одновременности**, показателем чего являются  **одинаковые видо-временные  формы глаголов** (прошедшее время, несовершенный вид).

Comment: А почему **"пока хватало глаза"** не может быть просто **обособленным обстоятельством**, выраженным фразеологическим выражением? Я вообще не так поняла смысл употребления фразеологизма...кто-то смотрит впереди рва и покуда хватает глаз (в смысле повсюду/в пределах видимости глаз) видит снег.  И, кстати первая и последняя части похожи...это все описание одного пейзажа. В первой говорится что находится _"впереди рва"_, а в последней - что _"ближе и левее"_ Мне оно все кажется одновременным... я запуталась уже...

Comment: Я бы тоже сказала, что по структуре это придаточное предложение: пока хватало глаза=пока было видно.

Comment: Так если это **фразеологическое выражение** - оно же должно выступать одним членом предложения...то есть мы не выделяем в нем сказуемое **"хватало"**...???

Comment: Насколько хватало глаз, ковром расстилались всё поля и поля, и нигде не было даже клочка леса (Мамин-Сибиряк).  Куда ни погляди, везде молодые лица. (Кетл.) В этих примерах устойчивые выражения с союзными словам имеют статус придаточного предложения.